Splitting table header labels
If I have a table as the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage{multirow} % For \multirow
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \resizebox
\usepackage{array} % For better column definitions

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table*}[!t]
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt} % Adjust column spacing
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.6} % Adjust row height
        \caption{Optimized Hyperparameters for each dataset and model.}
        \label{table:hyperparameters}
        \vskip 0.15in
        \begin{center}
            \begin{small}
                \begin{sc}
                    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ % Resize to fit text width
                        \begin{tabular}{l | c c | c c | c c | c c |}
                            \toprule
                            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Model1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Model2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Model3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Model4}} \\
                            \cline{2-9}
                            & $d'$ & \texttt{lr} & $d'$ & \texttt{lr} & $d'$ & \texttt{lr} & $d'$ & \texttt{lr} \\
                            \midrule
                            Dataset 1 & 128 & 6e-4 & 256 & 0.0005 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \hline
                            Dataset 2 & 64 & 0.01 & 128 & 0.0002 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \hline
                            Dataset 3 & 256 & 0.0005 & 512 & 0.0001 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \hline
                            Dataset 4 & 128 & 0.005 & 256 & 0.001 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \hline
                            Dataset 5 & 64 & 0.0002 & 128 & 0.01 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \hline
                            Dataset 6 & 256 & 0.001 & 64 & 0.005 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \hline
                            Dataset 7 & 512 & 0.0001 & 128 & 0.0005 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    }
                \end{sc}
            \end{small}
        \end{center}
        \vskip -0.1in
    \end{table*}
    
\end{document}


How can I separate the 'Dataset' Label in two parts with a diagonal line, where on the left I leave 'Datasets' and on the right I type 'Models' instead?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Off-topic: Don't use \begin{small}…\end{small}, just use \small. Don't use \begin{sc}…\end{sc}, just use \scshape (or better use \textsc{Dataset}).

Without MWE, I would recommend to use package tabularray and its diagbox library as shown in section 5.4 of the package manual.

Off-topic: Since you're using a one-column layout, there would appear to be no need for a table* environment -- a normal table environment should suffice.

Rather than implement your stated formatting objective -- and clutter up the table's "look" even more -- I'd simplify and declutter the table's appearance by getting rid of all vertical lines, using fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines, and omitting all bold-facing. Applying some more structure to the header material and aligning the numbers on their explicit or implicit decimal markers will also help.
And, unless you want the apparent font size of the table be many times larger than that of the rest of the document, don't use \resizebox. In fact, one should never use \resizebox on tabular material. Period.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]

\caption{Optimized hyperparameters for each dataset and model.}
\smallskip
%\small  % I can't see a reason for "\small"
\centering
\scshape % is this necessary?

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{T{3.0}T{1.4}} @{}}
\toprule
Dataset & \multicolumn{8}{c@{}}{Model} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{4} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
& {$d'$} & {lr} & {$d'$} & {lr} & {$d'$} & {lr} & {$d'$} & {lr} \\
\midrule
1 & 128 & 0.0006 & 256 & 0.0005 & 128 & 0.0001 & 128 & 0.0001 \\
2 &  64 & 0.01   & 128 & 0.0002 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 256 & 0.0005 & 512 & 0.0001 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 128 & 0.005  & 256 & 0.001  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
5 &  64 & 0.0002 & 128 & 0.01   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 256 & 0.001  &  64 & 0.005  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
7 & 512 & 0.0001 & 128 & 0.0005 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table} 
\end{document}

